# Support for tag flair

Tags: feature-request, tags, flair

User flair is a way to promote your *personal account* on Stack Exchange.

But for technologies or projects, it would be nice to link to "Tag flair".

For example: The Readme file for the [GitHub page for scikit-learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn) includes an explicit link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scikit-learn

Wouldn't it be nicer if they had some flair that included the SO logo, pointed out that there were currently ~11,311 questions with that tag - and perhaps what percentage were unanswered?

[Shields.io](http://shields.io) does offer a couple of Stack Exchange shields, but they are fairly limited (and a little flaky).

Shields example: (static screenshot)

[image: Shields example]